Sentry replays recorded but not accessible in replays view
I have missing replays
here is stats filtered by replays (stats window)

and here is replays (replays window )

what can be a reason that i dont see sessions i replays window ?
this is sentry self hosted , start script is:
   Sentry.browserTracingIntegration(),
      Sentry.replayIntegration({
        maskAllText: false,
        blockAllMedia: false
      })

    "replaysSessionSampleRate": 1.0,
    "replaysOnErrorSampleRate": 1.0,
    "tracesSampleRate": 1.0

UPDATE 1
here is recording stats :

like we see in every hour new recordings are created
so why in session replays tab i see newest session 22 hours ago ?

update 2
restart docker compose help - after few minutes i get old sessions :

but how keep alive session processor ? this instance run 2 days and every day self stop.
update 3
Im using Self-Hosted Sentry 23.4.0

could you please rephrase your wuation? i dont undertand what you mean by  “ what can be a reason that i dont see sessions i replays window ?”

Could this be due to an ad-blocker? so the replay never left the users browser?
if so, you can use a tunnel to proxy the events. https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/troubleshooting/#dealing-with-ad-blockers

i add example. its look like some recoeding processor is crashed ? recordings are counted. yesterdays i restart docker-compose and it back to showin. now not. i restart but dont see new session.

So its not ad blocker is saved but not processed i think , its stuck somewhere , when restart its back in few minutes

try updating your version of sentry to latest. which version are you on?

Self-Hosted Sentry 23.4.0

There are two consumers, the replay consumer must be running else you wouldn't see the replays in the list. When u click do you see a 404? I thought the description was about Windows replays though
